# How can I automatically create a folder, assign a home folder and logon script automatically after a new User is created?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, user-management

Usually I create a new user, then set the home folder, logon script, etc...

Is it possible in Active Directory when I create a new AD user object, that it goes out to my share drive and automatically creates a folder for them (naming it their username), and then assigns that folder as their home drive?

It would also be helpful if it would automatically assign them a specific logon script at user creation too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create or edit the user in the AD console, you can assign a home directory to their profile.

By using the %username% variable (e.g. `\\servername\sharename\%username%`) you can get it to automatically name according to the user name.

You can also use the `DSMOD` command to script creation, directory assignment, and many other tasks. A good explanation of using this command for home directory assignment (including for multiple users) [is here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/82c1dfba-8423-46af-841d-3ae23bea6f99/).

Comment: Ok I set this up in Active Directory, and it isn't creating the folder if it doesn't exist.  I create the folder manually and it still doesn't map the drive.  I chose I: as the letter and used \\servername\share\%username% for the path and it won't work.  Even when the folder exists.  I can path out to that share no problem on the machine.